# Create ec2 tags along with the creation of AMI using Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I got a python script that will create AMI for ec2 instances which are having the tag "Backup". Everything is working fine. Now, I need a small modification that the creating AMI's should also have the tag as the name of ec2 instance that is being used for AMI creation. I am very new scripting especially in python. Can some one help me in this?

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime 

#By the time I used this script, the Lamda is not available in Mumbai region. So, I chosen Singapore region.
#Specify the region in which EC2 Instances located and to create AMI's. Ex: Mumbai region (ap-south-1)
ec = boto3.client('ec2', 'ap-south-1')
#ec = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['Backup']},
            { 'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running'] }
        ]
         ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = sum(
        [
            [i for i in r['Instances']]
            for r in reservations
        ], [])

    print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)


    to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for instance in instances:
        print "Instance name:" + [res['Value'] for res in instance['Tags'] if res['Key'] == 'Name'][0]

        #Default retention for 7 days if the tag is not specified
        try:
            retention_days = [
                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 7
        except ValueError:
            retention_days = 7
        except Exception as e:    
            retention_days = 7

        finally:

            create_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            #create_fmt = create_time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y.%H.%M.%S')
            create_fmt = create_time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

            try:
                #Check for instance in running state
               # if(ec.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=[instance['InstanceId']],Filters=[{ 'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running'] }])['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Name'] == 'running'):    

                #To make sure instance NoReboot enabled and to name the AMI

                AMIid = ec.create_image(InstanceId=instance['InstanceId'], Name="Lambda - " + [result['Value'] for result in instance['Tags'] if result['Key'] == 'Name'][0] + " - " + " From " + create_fmt, Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance['InstanceId'], NoReboot=True, DryRun=False)
                to_tag[retention_days].append(AMIid['ImageId'])

                print "Retaining AMI %s of instance %s for %d days" % (
                        AMIid['ImageId'],
                        instance['InstanceId'],
                        retention_days,
                    )


                for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
                    delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
                    delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
                    print "Will delete %d AMIs on %s" % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)

                    #To create a tag to an AMI when it can be deleted after retention period expires
                    ec.create_tags(
                        Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
                        Tags=[
                            {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
                            ]
                        )
            #If the instance is not in running state        
            except IndexError as e:
                print "Unexpected error, instance "+[res['Value'] for res in instance['Tags'] if res['Key'] == 'Name'][0]+"-"+"\""+instance['InstanceId']+"\""+" might be in the state other then 'running'. So, AMI creation skipped."
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `create_tags()`, see the [documentations](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags).

```
response = client.create_tags(
    DryRun=True|False,
    Resources=[
        'string',
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
)
```

The name of instance will be stored as tag value with the key, Name. So, you can pick up the value by loop for the tag such as

```
for tag in instance['Tags']:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
        ec2Name = tag['Value']
```

Comment: I try to implement at my end it working perfect with Amazon Linux and Ubuntu OS but when i try to implement in Windows OS then i am getting error  to get the RDP of newly created instance